# Ping works but iperf shows no route to host

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, ping, iperf

We have two machines A and B, they can successfully ping each other, but when running iperf on a client-server mode, if A is in server mode and B is in client mode, B would directly show: `connect failed: No route to host`. But if A and B swap their roles, everything works perfectly fine. A and B can also ssh to each other successfully. The firewalls on both machines have been disabled and there is no package filtering. What might be the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are they on the same subnet / vlan, what is your network setup ?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but did you ever solve this? I am having exactly the same issue, ssh works both ways, ping works both ways, but I can't connect with anything else from B -> A, but A -> B works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably turn off the firewall, or allow the ports being used by iperf to go through the firewall. Sometimes the firewall will block iperf.